# How to display an adiabatic boundary condition in a diagram?

Tags: thermodynamics, technical-drawing

I want to create a diagram. It will consist of a plate with a uniform heat load, a heat sink, and an adiabatic boundary condition. I thought of displaying the sink as a rigid attachment (as in mechanical problems).

My question is: how do I display the adiabatic boundary conditions?

Comment: The convention is to use the rigid attachment symbol for adiabatic boundary conditions so it would be confusing to use it for a heat sink. Beyond that though I am not sure I understand the system you are trying to diagram. From what you describe you have a plate that has a heat load on one side and a heat sink on the other. The heat sink then is adiabatically bounded. I must be misunderstanding because that system would make no sense. Can you clarify the heat flow through your system?